# Proving $(\overline{A})'=A'$ if $(X,\tau)$ for $T_1$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and $A\subseteq X$
>
> Show $(\overline{A})'=A'$ if $(X,\tau)$ for $T_1$.

A $T_1$space is a topological space any $x,y\in X$ then there exists an open set $U$ such that $U\cap \{x,y\}={y}$.

So if $(X,\tau)$ is $T_1$, I can find $U\in\tau$ so that $a\in A$ and $a\in U$ so there are two options:
1) $U\subset A$ and $U\cap A\neq\emptyset$ then $a$ is a limit point. Since $a$ is arbitrary all the points in A are limit points.

2)If $U\cap Ext \{A\}\neq\emptyset$ and $U\cap A\neq \emptyset$ then there exists $x\in U$ so that $x\notin A$ and therefore $x$ is a limit point of $A$.

If only 1) is true then $\overline{A}=A\implies(\overline{A})'=A'$

If 2) is true then $A\subset \overline{A}$ so that $\overline{A}=A'\cup A$ so that $U\cap \overline{A}=U\cap(A\cup A')=(U\cap A)\cup (U \cap A)=U \cap A $ so that $(\overline{A})'=A'$

**Question**:

Is my proof right? If not. Could someone provide me an alternative proof?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof makes absolutely no sense to me. I provided my own below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that it is sufficient to show $A'' \subseteq A'$:

$\overline{A'} = A' \cup A'' \subseteq A'$ in that case, and the reverse inclusion is trivial.

I'll use the $T_1$-ness in that $x \in A'$ iff every open neighbourhood of $x$ contains infinitely many points of $A$. This fact holds in $T_1$ spaces, as is well-known.

If $x \in A''$ then let $O$ be any open neighbourhood of $x$.
Then $O$ contains a point $y \in A'$ and then $O$ must thus contain infinitely many points of $A$ (as $O$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ too and $y \in A'$), and so $x \in A'$ as required.

Comment: I do not know if I am thinking wrongly but $(\overline{A})'$ is the set of limit points of $\overline{A}$ and not the set of limit points of $A'$.

Comment: @PedroGomes It's the closure of the set of limit points. It rightly states that the set of limit points is a closed set in a $T_1$ space.

Comment: @PedroGomes $(\overline{A})' = (A \cup A')'  = A' \cup A'' = \overline{A'}$ so it comes to the same set.